# What's the use of some HTML5 tags?

Tags: html

I guess I'm stupid but I don't see what is the reason behind some new HTML5 tags.

Some tags, like `<audio>` and `<canvas>` provide some great new functionalities to the browser, but others such as `<article>`, `<section>` etc. just show up as a `<div>` or `<span>`. Therefore, why have these tags been added to HTML5?

I made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6BHAM/. In Chrome at least, there is no exciting layout or whatever. One could just use `<span>` / `<div>`.

So what's the use of those HTML5 tags which don't add new functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The semantics behind the tags are much more important than the resulting layout by a browser.  HTML is not only parsed by a browser, it can also be parsed by a **web crawler** or accessibility tools such as a **screen reader**.  A screen reader may add a particular emphasis for a certain tag used, or a web crawler could choose some content over others for the meta data it stores.

Further reading:

- [Semantic HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) - Wikipedia
- [Semantic HTML and Search Engine Optimization](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/semantic-html-and-search-engine-optimiza/) - dev.opera.com

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to make the HTML code more understandable as it was not created only for graphical rendering.

Using tags such as **article** or **section** make the HTML reading easier, and it also help you styling your page because you can use a different css for **article** than others div without adding a special class or id.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that HTML would allow more to give the semantic meaning of the encapsulated test rather than how it should be rendered.

This allows a cleaner separation of content structuring and content presentation.

Answer (score 2):

And it's best practice for SEO. robots will shearch and reference first in `article` before search in `nav` or `aside` area.

Answer (score 1):

HTML's purpose is to describe what a document *means* as opposed to what it looks like. The extensions are helpful to this end.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is we are moving to a [Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web). This is to help allow machines to understand the context of the information presented in a webpage.

The w3c defines a `<div>` as semantically meaningless and generic.

`The DIV and SPAN elements, in conjunction with the id and class attributes, offer a generic mechanism for adding structure to documents. These elements define content to be inline (SPAN) or block-level (DIV) but impose no other presentational idioms on the content.`

Now see the specification for `<article>`:

`The article element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.`